# extending of observable subclassing: [MobX] Options can't be provided for already observable objects

Tags: mobx, mobx-react-lite

When I create a deep structure with few extends I got this kind of error:

`Uncaught Error: [MobX] Options can't be provided for already observable objects.`

"mobx": "^6.4.2",
"mobx-react-lite": "^3.3.0",

All of code is just dirty example. real structure more complex.

Code example:

```
    import { makeObservable, observable, action } from 'mobx';

class DateMobx {
    date ;

    constructor(data) {
        this.date = new Date(data.date);
        makeObservable(this, { date: observable }, { autoBind: true });
    }
}
```

```
class Todo extends DateMobx {
    id = 0;
    title = 'title';
    text = 'text';

    constructor(todo) {
        super(todo);
        this.id  = todo.id;
        this.title  = todo.title;
        makeObservable(this, { id: observable,  title: observable, changeTitle: action }, { autoBind: true });
    }

    changeTitle= (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        this.title = value;
    }
}
```

```
class TodoList {
    todo = [];

    constructor() {
        const todoData = [{ id: 1, title: 'title', date: '123' }];
        this.todo = todoData.map(item => new Todo(item)); // ERROR happen here

        makeObservable(this, { todo: observable }, { autoBind: true });
    }
}
```

Error happen in constructor of TodoList class.

if remove `makeObservable` from `Todo` class, error is not reproduced but I need reactivity in that class.

If remove `extends DateMobx` from `Todo` class error also is not reproduces (but I have a lot of general classes with basic logic where I need reactivity too).

Why its happen and what should I do if I really need such kind of deep structure ?

Answer (score 0):

[Guys on github bring me the right solution](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3327)

Don't pass the third param `({ autoBind: true })` to `makeObservable` in subclasses. All options are "inherited" and can't be changed by subsequent `makeObservable` calls on the same object (this).

> options argument can be provided only once. Passed options are
> "sticky" and can NOT be changed later (eg. in subclass).

https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations